# Custom user model in django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-models

I want to create a custom user model using `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` as stated in the djangodocs:

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to
>   add some  additional profile information, you can simply subclass 
>   django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile
>   fields. This class provides the full implementation of the default
>   User as an abstract model.

So I inherited the `AbstractUser` class in my `Users` class and added a field. But when I run the `python manage.py syncdb` I get the following error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model login.users, which has either 
not been installed or is abstract.
```

I went through other questions on stackoverflow but couldn't resolve the error. Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib import admin

class Users(AbstractUser):
    college = models.CharField(max_length=40)

admin.site.register(Users, UserAdmin)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from login.models import Users
from django import forms

class UsersChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = Users

class UsersAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UsersChangeForm

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('college',)}),
    )


admin.site.register(Users, UsersAdmin)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'forms',
    'login',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.users'
```

**EDIT:**

I want to store the user information in the same table as `auth_user` and not in a new table.

Comment: is it a naming coalition? Can you try a different model name aside from  `class Users(AbstractUser):`

Comment: @Charlesliam after changing the name from `User` to `MyUser` and running `python manage.py syncdb` i get a new error `1146, Table stalker.login_myuser_user_permissions doesn't exist django`

Comment: Your new table for user related permission should be <appname>_<modelname>_user_permissions. Which I believed from your statement. Your application name is `login` and your modelname is `myuser`. You can try manually add the table to your db.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did this in one of my project. I was surprised to see that you extended User because [the doc says something else](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) :) You **can** extend Django User model, but if you only want to add new fields (not change its behavior), you should use a OneToOneField.

```
If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a one-to-one
relationship to a model containing the fields for additional information.
```

So, as you can see in the link, your code should look like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Or a ForeingKey to the College table?
    college = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    other_data = ...
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to store them in the same table as `auth_user`

Comment: in Django 1.5 you don't need additional table to extend User table.

Comment: @Nil, could you please check this question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/36191737/3350765

Answer (score 3):

It is a good practice to keep your code generic by using get_user_model() (to get the User model that is active in your project. Defined in django.contrib.auth) and AUTH_USER_MODEL (to reference the User model) rather than directly referring to the User model.

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    # Or a ForeingKey to the College table?
    college = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    other_data = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing this line in **models.py**:

`admin.site.register(Users, UserAdmin`)

I  figured out your error, You have the **INSTALLED_APPS** in the wrong order they should be the next:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'login',
    'forms',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "login.User"
```

> Why?

looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L26) **admin** uses the User model so maybe you can think:

But my user model is into **`login`** app and this one is before admin app, therefore **`login`** is installed before admin, why it does  not work?. That's because **`django.contrib.auth`**  is swappable (the model can be replaced for another one in your case has been swappable by login.User) so as you created a new User Model therefore  django has to change its user Model to the new one and then  you have to install the rest.

```
How must be at the moment of run syncdb:


1.- django.contrib.auth is installed, then this see if has been swapped, if yes it adds the new field or override completely the User Model (in your case only you add a field).

2.- admin, contentypes.... your apps, are installed and all works.

How you had it:

1.- login is installed (where the new User Model was, you put the AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings)

2.- Then forms.

3.- Then django tries to install the admin app but it can't because auth_user table hasn't been added that's because django.contrib.auth was after admin, therefore there is no User Model, this one isnt's swapped and this throws the error  **admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model login.users, which has either 
not been installed or is abstract.**
```

So accordingly first you always have to install the `django.contrib.auth` app and then all the apps that depends from.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work and I am getting the same error message

Comment: HOw did you order the INSTALLED_APPS? Is admin after auth?

Comment: yup I ordered it the same way you mentioned

Comment: Do you have a foreign Key to User in the forms app?

Comment: @Victor, I extended the default User table by using `AbstractUser`. The admin run smoothly but when I try to add new user after clicking save I'm getting an error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`, yet I have a table in my Oracle db and I have it on my Model.py.

Comment: @Victor I don't have any foriegn key to User in forms app

Comment: @ArchitVerma I think you have a problem in another place, add me to facebook to see the problem

Comment: I created a synonyms for my current table `CCAD'.`CCAD_OFFICIAL_RECEIPT` to `OFFICIAL_RECEIPT`. It's giving me an error if I try to duplicate the table name. So far my problem with saving was caused by `DJANGO_ADMIN_LOG` table with a foreign key field name user_id still  referencing the old `AUTH_USER` table. I  change there reference to my new `NAFD_USER`. It's now saving properly. But when I try to delete record i still get this error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. Weird..This problem only occured after upgrading from django 1.4.1 to 1.6.><