# want to do authentication using django rest framework, i want to setup the login route for mentors and other users and preserve some end points

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Basically i want to authenticate the current user using user_details model and also to check if current user is a mentor and establish authorisation for the endpoints and preserve some endpoints from user**
**But i am not able to understand how to achieve it**

**my models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class LiveClass(models.Model):
    standard = models.IntegerField()
    no_of_students_registered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Class'

class User_details(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User_details'


class Mentor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    details = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mentors'


class LiveClass_details(models.Model):
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    chapter_details = models.TextField()
    mentor_name = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, max_length=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'LiveClass_details'

class LiveClass_registration(models.Model):
    class_details = models.OneToOneField(LiveClass_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.OneToOneField(User_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta: 
         verbose_name_plural = 'LiveClass_registration'
```

**my serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models



class LiveClass_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass
        fields = '__all__'


class User_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User_details
        fields = '__all__'


class LiveClass_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass_details
        fields = '__all__'

class Mentor_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Mentor
        fields = '__all__'

class LiveClass_registration_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass_registration
        fields = '__all__'
```

**my urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('liveclass_api.urls'))
]
```

**my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import generics


from . import serializers
from . import models
# Create your views here.

class ListLiveClass(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

class ListMentors(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.Mentor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.Mentor_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**complete github code** : https://github.com/dhruv354/django-liveclass.git

Comment: if you want to use a customer user then it's better to subclass AbstractUser https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: Can you add the intial implementation of it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create custom user model for different user types using django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64577709/how-can-i-create-custom-user-model-for-different-user-types-using-django-rest-fr)